# Non blocking CSV read

Tags: java

We have code that reads CSV in Threads using **BufferedReader**. For example if five CSV are to be upload then five thread will be opened reading different CSV file and using its own **BufferedReader**. Recently we noticed that when six upload are running on same time the CSV reading become slow on further investigation we found that

> CSV were not read simultaneously.

When one thread finish reading one line then other thread start reading CSV line.

> The CSV reading was happening in sequential order while each CSV
>   upload was running in independent thread not sharing BufferedReader or
>   Same CSV file.

```
class CSVUplod extends Thread{
    private String fileName;
    private String filePath;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            csvUploadFn();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public CSVUpload(String fileName , String filePath){
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.filePath = filePath;
        Thread T = new Thread(this);
        T.start();  
    }


private boolean csvUploadFn(){
    try {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filePath+fileName)));
        String csvLine = bf.readLine();
        do {
        //read line and add into DB
            csvLine = bf.readLine();
        } while(csvLine!=null);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return true;
    }   
}
```

So what should be the problem any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: If you spawns thread correctly, they won't interfere each other. Because they're sharing nothing. There must be something else.

Comment: You should post your code here

Comment: Ok give me a min.

Comment: How are you determining whether it's running sequentially or concurrently?

Comment: I added some logs in while loop and started six thread at the same time and the log output showed they were running sequentially. 12 - 15 line per second were read.

Answer (score 0):

You're starting your thread inside your constructor, while it's not fully initialized. And this will cause unexpected behaviors.

```
public CSVUpload(String fileName , String filePath){
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.filePath = filePath;
    Thread T = new Thread(this); // `this` is not fully constructed yet
    T.start();  
}
```

Start thread outside your constructor and see if the problem fixed.

```
public CSVUpload(String fileName , String filePath){
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.filePath = filePath;
}
```

And outside the class:

```
CsvUpload csvUploader = new CsvUpload("", "");
csvUploader.start();
```